# Time series analysis with known outliers

Tags: time-series

Let's say I have a time series of site usage data that I would like to analyze. The data is for people visiting my site, with a known seasonality that I can easily calculate, but in addition, there are also events (say the day when a social media post gets a lot of shares, or I purchase ads) that are scheduled, but are not at any regular cadence. Is there a way to add this source of variability to my model in a way that allows me to make a better estimate of my baseline trend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first test your data in an autocorrelation plot to double check that your popular social media post and ads are random over time and if it is random a Box-Jenkins model should still be able to account for the variability of your model and predict where your data will trend.

Comment: Say that the assumptions of randomness are met, can I use the model with known future events to generate a more accurate forecast?

Comment: Well generally the more data for your time-series the more accurate you can predict the future data point here is a good link on time-series and predictions. http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section4/pmc4.htm

Comment: Hope this site can help with any additional questions you have.

Comment: I'm actually fairly familiar with trends and seasonality in time series forecasting, but don't know what to do with events (such as increased site usage due to an upcoming event) that I know about ahead of time, but occurs randomly.